# How does VPN work?

Tags: vpn

I'm thinking of buying a VPN service and i watched this tutorial video on how to set it up. Pretty much straight forward using Windows 7 Network and Sharing Center to set up a new VPN.

But while enabled, is it 100% guaranteed that every application on evry port uses it? How does the VPN connection "take over" the regular connection?

Answer (score 3):

Three parts to this answer.

1) Many VPNs have an option, to route (or not) all traffic through it. This option is present because one the uses of a VPN (by no menas the only one) is to allow safe access to the resources present on the VPN server's LAN. If this option is present on a given VPN, then, in order to re-direct all of your network traffic through it you will have to activate this option. If however you are thinking of a `commercial` VPN server, then the option does not exist because no one is interested in accessing the server's LAN, and the only service of interest is that making your browsing private.

2) VPNs work by re-writing your routing table, which knows nothing of ports and services. So they really convey all of your traffic through their server, in encrypted form.

3) This scheme breaks down with DNS requests. DNS requests are used to translate symbolic addresses (www.nytimes.com) into numerical form (= 170.149.168.130). These requests precede your loading of any Web page, and should be routed through the VPN. But occasionally it happens that your operating system insists on using its own DNS-servers in plain text form, so that each page request and load, which occurs in encrypted form, is actually associated with a plain text request which, if intercepted, will reveal your browsing activity.

It is difficult to avoid DNS leakages (the technical name for this breakdown of secrecy), but you can find helpful Web pages on the NEt, like [dnsleaktes.com](https://www.dnsleaktest.com/) which will help you assess the extent of the problem for any available service. Also, a Google search reveals a bevvy of information about just abut any commercial VPN provider.